# Java check if child is implementing interface

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, abstract

I want to do some stuff just by implementing interface (without writing body in child class)

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
interface I{
    void foo();
}
```

Class with feature `I`:

```
class A extends C implements I{


}
```

Class without feature `I`:

```
class B extends C {

}
```

Parent class:

```
class C implements I{
    @Override
    public void foo(){
        // if child is implementing interface dirctly it should do stuff
        // Skip this otherwise 
    }
}
```

But how to check if my `A` class is **directly** implementing `I` interface? To make it like this:

Main:

```
class Main {
    public Main() {
        I classA = new A();
        classA.foo(); // do stuff

        I classB = new B(); // <- not crash because C is implementing I interface
        classB.foo(); // empty
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean? if the method `foo` is overriden by `A`? Otherwise the compiler will tell you if `A` inherits from `I`

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: not clear what you are trying to ask here..but you may try using `instanceof`

Comment: What you've said is incorrect. First, "Class A with feature I" - it already implements I from the parent class C, no need to write "implements I" here. Second, "Class (B) without feature I" - incorrect, since B extends C which implements I, class B also implements I. I think you're confusing yourself here... try making class C NOT implement I and you'll get a compiler error as I suspect you might want to see.

Comment: @vikingsteve yes I know -> this is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @vikingsteve plus I dont want to write Override code in class A. I want to make class C to be responsible for body of `foo()` method

Comment: Well in the code above both `classA.foo()` and `classB.foo()` will "do stuff" the same way, since it's implemented in class C

Comment: Thats why I'm asking a question - This code is for explaining what I'm trying to do. And I know its wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whilst this would make no sense in terms of polymorphism here´s something with which you could check if the class does implement `I` directly.

```
package example;

public class A extends B implements I{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        new A().foo();
        new B().foo();
        new C().foo();
    }
}
class B extends C{

} 
class C implements I{

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        boolean implementsDirectly = false;
        for (Class c : getClass().getInterfaces()) {
            if(c.getName().equals("example.I")) {
                implementsDirectly = true;
            }
        }
        if(implementsDirectly) {
            System.out.println("The class " + getClass().getName() +" does implement I directly in the class definition");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The class " + getClass().getName() +" does not implement I directly in the class definition");
        }
    }

}

interface I {
    void foo();
}
```

output:

```
The class example.A does implement I directly in the class definition
The class example.B does not implement I directly in the class definition
The class example.C does implement I directly in the class definition
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `if (A instanceof I)`.
This should work

Comment: that makes no sense, the result is known at compile time if A is a class. for example if A was a String and I was RandomAccess, this would not even compile

Answer (score 0):

If you know the methods name, you can check for it using reflection:

```
class Main {
  public main() throws Exception{
    I classA = new A();
    boolean implementsIByItself=true;
    try{
      classA.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("foo", new Class[0]);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme){
      //Exception will be thrown if A doesnt declare "foo"
      implementsIByItself=false;
    }

  }
}
```

`getDeclaredMethod` will only return a `Method` object if the class it is called on does not just inherit it, but declares it.

Keep in mind this is not a very clean approach and there might be more suitable solutions. Your problem looks like a flaw in design if you are depending on knowing which class changes behavior by overriding a method.